# WebRTC Remote Video Not Showing up when pressing Answer Button

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, webrtc

So I'm currently learning WebRTC to make a video chat web app. Currently it can create a calls string, but when I put that value into the text box on another end and press the answer button, the remote video will not show.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Start Webcam</h2>
    <div class ="videos">
      <span>
        <h3>Local</h3>
        <video id="webcamVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
      </span>
      <span>
        <h3>Remote</h3>
        <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
      </span>
    </div>

    <button id = "webcamButton">Start Webcam</button>
    <h2>Create a New Call</h2>
    <button id = "callButton" >Call</button>

    <input id="callInput" />
    <button id = "answerButton" >Answer</button>
    <button id = "hangupButton">Hangup</button>
    <script type ="module" src ="/main.js"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import './style.css'
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';


// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBhfGe2piS290fQcev6WOWyDW_63dTRlkI",
  authDomain: "videochat-ce8a5.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "videochat-ce8a5",
  storageBucket: "videochat-ce8a5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "552989205603",
  appId: "1:552989205603:web:5f47d21390a92a11884456",
  measurementId: "G-HCFMHVGKQD"
};


// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = firebase.firestore();




const servers = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};


// Global State
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
let localStream = null;
let remoteStream = null;

const webcamButton = document.getElementById('webcamButton');
const webcamVideo = document.getElementById('webcamVideo');
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const callInput = document.getElementById('callInput');
const answerButton = document.getElementById('answerButton');
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

webcamButton.onclick = async ()=>{
  localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
  remoteStream = new MediaStream();

  localStream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{
    pc.addTrack(track,localStream);
  });

  pc.ontrack = event =>{
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
  };

  webcamVideo.srcObject = localStream;
  remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;

};


callButton.onclick = async () =>{
  const callDoc = firestore.collection('calls').doc();
  const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');
  const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
  
  callInput.value = callDoc.id;

  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    event.candidate && offerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
  };

  const offerDescription = await pc.createOffer();
  await pc.setLocalDescription(offerDescription);
  
  const offer = {
    sdp: offerDescription.sdp,
    type: offerDescription.type,
  };

  await callDoc.set({offer});

  pc.ontrack = (event) => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
  };



  callDoc.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
    const data = snapshot.data();
    if(!pc.currentRemoteDescription && data?.answer){
      const answerDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
      pc.setRemoteDescription(answerDescription);
    }

  });

  answerCandidates.onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change)=>{
      if(change.type === 'added'){
        const canidate = new RTCIceCandidate(change.doc.data());
        pc.addIceCandidate(canidate);
      }
    })
  })
};


answerButton.onclick = async()=>{
  const callId = callInput.value;
  const callDoc = firestore.collection('calls').doc(callId);
  const answerCandidates = callDoc.collection('answerCandidates');
  const offerCandidates = callDoc.collection('offerCandidates');

  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    event.cancelable && answerCandidates.add(event.candidate.toJSON());
  };

  const callData = (await callDoc.get()).data();

  const offerDescription = callData.offer;
  await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerDescription));

  const answerDescription = await pc.createAnswer();
  await pc.setLocalDescription(answerDescription);

  const answer ={
    type:answerDescription.type,
    sdp: answerDescription.sdp,
  };

  await callDoc.update({answer});
  
  pc.ontrack = (event) => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
  };

  offerCandidates.onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change)=>{
      console.log(change)
      if(change.type === 'added'){
        let data = change.doc.data();
        pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
      }
    })
  })

}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

I tried updating the tracks in the answer and call onclick handlers.